# PHP preg_match to find relevant word

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match, str-replace

I have a variable with value like this :

```
$sentence = "When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, be aware of how your carrier handles renewals";
```

And I have array variables with value below :

```
$searches = array('aware', 'aware of', 'be aware', 'be aware of');

$replaces = array('conscious', 'conscious of', 'remember', 'concentrate on');
```

I would like to find just 'be aware of' and then replace with 'concentrate on'. Output like below :

> When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, concentrate on how your carrier handles renewals

Search only 'be aware of' as relevant synonym replacement not others. Thanks for your help.

Ok, here the new code:

```
$searches = array('aware of', 'be aware of', 'be aware', 'aware');

$replaces = array('conscious of', 'concentrate on', 'remember', 'conscious');
```

This is a dynamic array (`$searches`), I hope you understand...and we know to get the best synonym replacement is use ''be aware of' to replace with 'concentrate on'. Output like below :

> When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, concentrate on how your carrier handles renewals

Comment: Order the search patterns by string length. And possibly use `\b` anchors around them.

Comment: Please show the code in php please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$sentence = "When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, be aware of how your carrier handles renewals";
$searches = array('aware', 'aware of', 'be aware', 'be aware of');
$replaces = array('conscious', 'conscious of', 'remember', 'concentrate on');

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) return -1;
    if (strpos($b, $a) !== false) return 1;
    return 0;
}

uasort($searches, 'cmp');
$replaces_new = array();
$i=0;
foreach($searches as $k=>$v) {
    $replaces_new[$i] = $replaces[$k];
    $i++;
}

$res = str_replace($searches, $replaces_new, $sentence);
echo $res;
```

**output:**

```
When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, concentrate on how your carrier handles renewals
```

Comment: Thanks M42. Perfect solution for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your search & replace array are static.

Try this,

`str_replace($searches[3],$replaces[3],$sentence)`

Also to just replace specific "beware of" you can do simply by:

`str_replace("%be aware of%","concentrate on",$sentence)`

Comment: Please note, I just need replace relevant synonyms from $searches that have identical word. It not problem from where the biggest match first.

Comment: Ya, so in that case simply use `str_replace($searches, $replaces, $subject);`

Comment: Just search match synonym from $searches to replace, and we know the true synonym is "be aware of". How to do it?

Comment: This is a dynamic replacement for variable searches to search relevance synonym. I think you know what I mean.. Try to find how match occurs in $sentence from $searches, not only re-order with simple_replace re-ordered.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regexp here,

First sort your constant array in a way, that it finds the biggest match first:

```
$searches = array('be aware of', 'aware of', 'be aware', 'aware');
$replaces = array('concentrate on', 'conscious of', 'remember', 'conscious');
```

then use str_replace

```
$newsentence=str_replace($searches,$replaces, $sentence);
```

Comment: Please note, I just need replace relevant synonyms from $searches that have identical word. It not problem from where the biggest match first.

Comment: @XioJin This is why I reordered `$replaces` the same way, I reordered `$searches`

Comment: $searches is dynamic array, you cannot ordered the values. Just search match synonym to replace, and we know the true synonym is "be aware of"

Comment: @XioJin As long as it is guaranteed, that $searches and $replaces are in the correct order ($searches[$i] corresponds to $replaces[$i] for all valid $i) you are OK.

Comment: Yeach..I know that! But this is a dynamic replacement for variable searches to search relevance synonym. I think you know what I mean.. Try to find how match occurs in $sentence from $searches, not only re-order with simple_replace re-ordered.

Comment: @XioJin this is exactly what that code does! Out of the scope of this you create your synonym arrays (which ofcourse have to correspond), then you order them in a way, that makes bigger matches come first, the you str_replace()

Comment: Ok, here the new code :

$searches = array('aware of', 'be aware of', 'be aware', 'aware');

$replaces = array('conscious of', 'concentrate on', 'remember', 'conscious');

How you will order the array? This is a dynamic array, I hope you understand...and we know to get the best synonym replacement is use ''be aware of' to replace with 'concentrate on'

Answer (score 1):

If you change the order of your searches so that the first element can not match an element later in the array, you can use `str_replace($searches, $replaces, $subject);` normally!

```
$searches = array('be aware of', 'be aware', 'aware of', 'aware');
$replaces = array('concentrate on', 'remember', 'conscious of', 'conscious');
```

If the string contains "be aware", "be aware of" will not match and "be aware" will. If you'd have the opposite order, "aware" would match "be aware" which would be wrong.

Comment: Please note, I just need replace relevant synonyms from $searches that have identical word. It not problem from where the biggest match first.

Comment: @XioJin Where do you get the searches and replaces from anyway? If it's from SQL, you can sort using SQL which would be much easier...