# PHP preg_match or str_replace to find relevant synonyms

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a print_r variable array like this :

$synonyms =

array
 (

```
[0] => a company|an organization|a business
[1] => auto|automobile|car|vehicle
[2] => aware|conscious|mindful|informed|knowledgeable
[3] => aware of|conscious of|mindful of
[4] => be aware|bear in mind|remember
[5] => be aware of|concentrate on|pay attention to|know about|be familiar with
[6] => carefully|cautiously|meticulously|very carefully|thoroughly|properly
[7] => cases|instances|circumstances|situations|scenarios|conditions
[8] => comes|arrives|will come|happens
[9] => company|business|organization|firm|corporation|provider
[10] => coverage|protection
[11] => in most|in many
[12] => in most cases|generally|usually|normally|typically|most often
[13] => in the|within the|inside the|while in the|from the|during the
[14] => increases|raises|will increase|boosts|improves
[15] => information|info|data|details|facts|information and facts
[16] => insurance|insurance coverage|insurance policy|insurance plan|insurance policies
[17] => on the|around the|within the|to the|about the|over the
[18] => once|as soon as|when|after|the moment|at the time
[19] => once you|when you|as soon as you|after you|when you finally
[20] => or a|or perhaps a|or possibly a|or even a|or maybe a|or simply a
[21] => package|package deal|bundle|deal|offer
[22] => payment|fee|cost
[23] => policy|coverage|plan
[24] => premium|top quality|high quality
[25] => question|query|concern|issue|problem
[26] => rates|prices|charges|premiums|costs|fees
[27] => receive|get|obtain|acquire|be given
[28] => receive a|get a
[29] => representative|consultant
[30] => review|evaluation|assessment|critique|overview|evaluate
[31] => the new|the brand new|the newest|the modern
[32] => time to|time for you to
[33] => with your|together with your|along with your|with the
[34] => you have|you've|you've got|you might have|you may have|you have got
```

);

And here my sentence =

$sentence = "When it comes time to renew your auto insurance policy, **be aware of** how your carrier handles renewals. In most cases, you receive a renewal package in the mail with your new policy and rates. Review this information carefully, and question any increases in premium with your agent or a company representative. In most cases, once you submit a payment on the new policy, you have renewed your coverage.";

Here my example code to replace with relevant synonyms for standard rewriter softwares:

> ```
> $searches =  array();
>
> for ($i=0; $i < count($synonyms); $i++) {
>    $words = explode("|", $synonyms[$i], 3);
>    $searches[$i] = $words[0];
>    $replaces[$i] = $synonyms[$i];
> }
>
> function cmp($a,$b) {
>    if ($a == $b) return 0;
>    if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) return -1;
>    if (strpos($b, $a) !== false) return 1;
>    return 0;
> }
>
> uasort($searches, 'cmp');
>
> $replaces_new = array();
>
> $i=0;
>
> foreach ($searches as $k=>$v) {
>    $replaces_new[$i] = "{{$replaces[$k]}}";
>    $i++;
> }
>
> $output = str_replace($searches, $replaces_new, $output);
>
> echo $output;
>
> ## This code was modified from here :
> ## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031199/php-preg-match-to-find-relevant-word
> ```

I got output like this :

When it {comes|arrives|will come|happens} {time to|time for you to} renew your {auto|automobile|car|vehicle} {insurance|insurance {coverage|protection}|insurance policy|insurance plan|insurance policies} {policy|{coverage|protection}|plan}, **{{be {aware|conscious|mindful|informed|knowledgeable}|bear in mind|remember} of|concentrate on|pay attention to|know about|be familiar with}** how your carrier handles renewals. In most {cases|instances|circumstances|situations|scenarios|conditions}, you {{receive|get|obtain|acquire|be given} a|get a} renewal {package|package deal|bundle|deal|offer} {in the|within the|inside the|while in the|from the|during the} mail {with your|together with your|along with your|with the} new {policy|{coverage|protection}|plan} and {rates|prices|charges|premiums|costs|fees}. Review this {information|info|data|details|facts|information and facts} {carefully|cautiously|meticulously|very carefully|thoroughly|properly}, and {question|query|c{once|as soon as|when|after|the moment|at the time}rn|issue|problem} any {increases|raises|will increase|boosts|improves} in {premium|top quality|high quality} {with your|together with your|along with your|with the} agent {or a|or perhaps a|or possibly a|or even a|or maybe a|or simply a} {company|business|organization|firm|corporation|provider} {representative|consultant}. In most {cases|instances|circumstances|situations|scenarios|conditions}, {{once|as soon as|when|after|the moment|at the time} you|when you|as soon as you|after you|when you finally} submit a {payment|fee|cost} on {the new|the brand new|the newest|the modern} {policy|{coverage|protection}|plan}, {you have|you've|you've got|you might have|you may have|you have got} renewed your {coverage|protection}.

and this is the output I wish :

$output = "When it {comes|arrives|will come|happens} {time to|time for you to} renew your {auto|automobile|car|vehicle} {insurance|insurance coverage|insurance policy|insurance plan|insurance policies} {policy|coverage|plan}, **{be aware of|concentrate on|pay attention to|know about|be familiar with}** how your carrier handles renewals. {In most cases|Generally|Usually|Normally|Typically|Most often}, you {receive a|get a} renewal {package|package deal|bundle|deal|offer} {in the|within the|inside the|while in the|from the|during the} mail {with your|together with your|along with your|with the} new {policy|coverage|plan} and {rates|prices|charges|premiums|costs|fees}. {Review|Evaluation|Assessment|Critique|Overview|Evaluate} this {information|info|data|details|facts|information and facts} {carefully|cautiously|meticulously|very carefully|thoroughly|properly}, and {question|query|concern|issue|problem} any {increases|raises|will increase|boosts|improves} in {premium|top quality|high quality} {with your|together with your|along with your|with the} agent {or a|or perhaps a|or possibly a|or even a|or maybe a|or simply a} {company|business|organization|firm|corporation|provider} {representative|consultant}. {In most cases|Generally|Usually|Normally|Typically|Most often}, {once you|when you|as soon as you|after you|when you finally} submit a {payment|fee|cost} {on the|around the|within the|to the|about the|over the} new {policy|coverage|plan}, {you have|you've|you've got|you might have|you may have|you have got} renewed your {coverage|protection}."

Note : 
"**be aware of**" will be replaced with "**{be aware of|concentrate on|pay attention to|know about|be familiar with}**" instead other words like "aware", "be aware" and "aware of" for the best relevant synonyms.

How to do that?? THanks for your help.

Comment: You have accepted an answer to your last question. You shouldn't have done that if that doesn't really solve your problem. Inquiring about the same topic again and again is not welcome. -- And you have been told the same thing (group by size) before. Make a map with `array_combine($searches,$replaces)` and sort by length before replacing.

Comment: if I'm combine between $searches and $replaces how I can replace to sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of the replacement.  Your code is finding "aware" first, then "be aware", and replacing both of these before "be aware of."  If you want *this* method to work, you're probably going to have to re-order the `$synonyms` array to have the most specific phrases to find first, followed by the most general ("be aware of" before "aware").

Comment: That's why I need a solution to re-order or just find the relevant phrase instead other phrases :(

Comment: Reordering would be as simple as changing the index into the array.  Right now you have them alphabetical.  Just renumber.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, if possible, would be to mark all of the possible replacements so that they are certain not to overlap.

ex:

```
$sentence = "When it ::comes:: ::time to:: renew your ::auto:: ::insurance:: ::policy::"
```

Now you need to change the top of the code to:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($synonyms); $i++) {
   $words = explode("|", $synonyms[$i], 3);
   $searches[$i] = "::".$words[0]."::"; // Change this line
   $replaces[$i] = $synonyms[$i];
}
```